# [AndroidStudio]How to make toast inside the Text Watcher function ? (What context should i pass in)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am using the `TextWatcher()` method to listen on my `EditText`.
It has a method called `afterTextChanged(Editable s)`
I want to display a `Toast` saying "Changes saved" in this method.

For the `Toast.makeText(Context context, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

What context I should pass in ??. I have already tried this and "`name_of_Fragment.this`" but it wont work.

Anybody knows what to do ??

```
 mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //Nothing to do!!
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //save the text and overwrite
            mCrime.setTitle(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // I want the Toast here!!


        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: If u r trying this in fragment use getActivity().

Comment: Probably TextChangedListner may get hanged if you do continuous text changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
getActivity();
```

this may helps you

Comment: that won't work, inside of the TextWatcher object `this` refers to the TextWatcher. You probably meant `name_of_Fragment.this.getActivity()` as mentioned above

Comment: yeah, right. @ MidasLefko . see my edited answer